# how to put click event on single button so it goes to previous activity in android

Tags: android, button, android-intent, back

I have made an application in that i have an activity contains a TextView and a button.Now this activity is used multiple times in the application so i want is that when i click the back button in that activity ,it should go to the previous activity.In short it should work as back button of device.My code is as below:

this activity is used in 4 activities ,

So i have tried as below:

**Advance_help.java**

```
package com.theappgeeks.kevingreenwealth;

import java.text.BreakIterator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AdvanceHelp extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button btn;
Calculator_1Activity cal1 =new Calculator_1Activity();
Calculator2 cal2 =new Calculator2();
Calculator_3Activity cal3 =new Calculator_3Activity();
Calculator_4Activity cal4 =new Calculator_4Activity();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advance_help);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        /*btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(btn.)
            Intent i1=new Intent(AdvanceHelp.this,Calculator_1Activity.class);  
            startActivity(i1);

            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_advance_help, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.equals(cal1)){
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i1= new Intent(AdvanceHelp.this,Calculator_1Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                }

            });

        }
        else if(v.equals(cal2)){
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i1= new Intent(AdvanceHelp.this,Calculator2.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                }

            });

        }

        else if(v.equals(cal3)){
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i1= new Intent(AdvanceHelp.this,Calculator2.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                }

            });

        }

        else if(v.equals(cal4)){
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i1= new Intent(AdvanceHelp.this,Calculator2.class);
                    startActivity(i1);
                }

            });

        }
        else
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(AdvanceHelp.this,MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me as soon as possible..thank you
in advance

Comment: use finish(); function where u want to go into back activity.

Comment: super.onBackPressed(); - should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad programming practice,

As you already `implements OnClickListener`

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and remove

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

from

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
```

And for

```
i want is that when i click the back button in that activity ,it should go to the previous
activity.In short it should work as back button of device.My code is as below:
```

Just call Activity's `finish()` in button's click() on which you want..

Comment: I have doubt on your code.. `if(v.equals(cal1)){` where you are comparing View with `Calculator_1Activity`. Too bad..!

Comment: and thanx for you review about my coding..i promise i will make it better ...have a good day.:)

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the Method `onBackPressed()`. This Method is also called when you Push the Back Button.

Answer (score 0):

For backpressed and finishing the above answers are true but this is not an appropriate question you having one button and you want to call 4 activity that's not possible...!!!! because you are comparing it with id and that only matters when you have more than on button.....!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

in your `onClick(View v)` method call either `super.OnBackPressed()` to emulate the back button being pressed, or call `finish()` to end the current activity and go back to the previous activity that was running